# My keyboard entry mode says it's Irish, but isn't

Tags: keyboard-layout

As of today,

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> gives me the @ symbol and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> gives me ". (The at sign and the double quotation mark have swapped places.)
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> no longer produces the € symbol.

This tells me that my keyboard has switched to some non-Irish mode, probably American. And yet, up at the top right of my screen I see an **Ie**, and if I click on it I see that the Irish option, which is the only option, is selected. What gives?

> [image: Screenshot of menu described above]

The keyboard layout chart shows much as I’d expect, with the ", @, and € symbols where I’d expect to see them:

> [image: Keyboard layout chart: Title says "Irish"]

And the text entry settings also show Irish as the only available option:

> [image: Import sources to use: Irish]

So if everything tells me that I have an Irish keyboard, and if it worked as an Irish keyboard till yesterday, why is it suddenly not an Irish keyboard today? And what can I do about it?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/126518/652.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

to reconfigure the console keyboard layout. Then run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Comment: €@". Wonderful. The first of those fixed the € problem (I explicitly told it to use the right alt key, rather than leaving it at default. I left all other options at default.) The second put @ and " in their proper places, though I'm at a loss to understand why. Why do console settings affect keyboard layout? Anyway, it works. Thanks.

Comment: This happens often enough that I now have `function fix_keyboard { sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration; sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup; }` in my `.bash_aliases`.